How to identify and uninstall packages installed as dependencies during custom backport creation?
I'm using the method on the link below to create a custom Debian backport, ex. for packages that are otherwise not yet backported but exist in testing branch:
https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation
Now I would like to undo installed backport package however simply running sudo apt purge <package_name> is not enough because I see some packages have been installed that survive the purge. (I see them in application menu and can run them)
Question is how to identify all the extra packages that were installed to be able to purge them as well?
I still have build directory that was used to build the backport.
If I run sudo less /var/log/apt/history.log the log will show only the backport but will not show those extra packages that were installed.
The specific package that I currently want to purge as well as dependencies is crow-translate:
https://packages.debian.org/trixie/crow-translate
The extra packages in this specific case that I see in application menu are:

QT 5 Assistant
QT 5 Designer
QT 5 Linguist

But I believe there are more that are not visible in application menu.

For a given source package foo, mk-build-deps works by creating a foo-build-deps package with all of foo’s build dependencies as “real” dependencies. Installing foo-build-deps then pulls in all those dependencies automatically, and removing foo-build-deps makes them candidates for auto-removal (with some caveats).
Thus to remove the packages which were installed when you backported the crow-translate package, you need to undo two steps:

the mk-build-deps step, which created and installed a crow-translate-build-deps package;
the initial package installation, sudo apt install packaging-dev debian-keyring devscripts equivs (I’m assuming all those packages were new to your system).

To do this, and remove all the packages which were automatically installed (and any other automatically-installed packages which are no longer necessary), run
sudo apt purge --autoremove crow-translate-build-deps packaging-dev debian-keyring devscripts equivs


Can you tell me how did you learn that crow-translate-build-deps was installed? is there a command to learn that from CLI for any backport and not specific one?

That’s how mk-build-deps works: for a given soirce package foo, it creates a foo-build-deps package depending on all of foo’s build dependencies. In the wiki page that’s coreutils-build-deps, in your case it’s crow-translate-build-deps.
